# Problems with grub with our RAID10 Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, hardware-raid, grub2, boot-loader

We have a Dell PowerEdge R730xd with 24 SSDs of 500GB each.
We need to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on this machine, and use it as a database (postgresql).

Our RAID controller is an Avago MEGARAID, and to my knowledge it behaved exactly like a H310 card.

I set up 2 Virtual Drives in RAID10 (16 and 8), so we have now

- `/dev/sda` (4TB)
- `/dev/sdb` (2TB)

I'm having troubles installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Even by choosing the most automatic installation (Guided: use entire disk `/dev/sda`) upon boot i get welcomed by the Grub rescue mode, with the message

```
attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
```

By executing some commands in grub rescue mode, I encountered these devices

- `(hd0,gpt3)`, unknown filesystem, should be the `swap` partition
- `(hd0,gpt2)`, recognized as `ext2` partition, contains `/boot` folder, but trying to access that returns the same error (*attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'*)
- `(hd0,gpt1)`,  recognized as *unknown filesystem*, it should be a `BIOSgrub` partition (we're in GPT mode after all)
- `(hd1)`, the 2TB drive

Trying to reinstall grub into `/dev/sda` using the Ubuntu LiveCD did not help. We're still welcomed by the same error. I could mount `/dev/sda2` in rescue mode and check the content of `grub.cfg`, but i'm not really sure what needs to be checked. Everywhere it was correctly referencing `(hd0,gpt2)`

Even after running boot-repair we get welcomed by the same error:

- Here is the `boot-info` of the system: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23726916/
- Here is the output of `boot-repair`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23726925/

Comment: First, I will just mirror the OS drive instead of putting them into a single RAID 10 strip.  It is a bad idea to put OS swap on RAID strip. If allowed, I will dedicated a drive for database TEMP file processing.  
Second, did you check the RAID controller support for SSD TRIM ?

Comment: In addition, if your RAID controller are having a ridiculous low queue depth like PERC H310, you will going hit bottleneck, even with a top notch SSD  
http://serverfault.com/questions/769438/will-a-h310-mini-or-a-h200-support-samsung-ssds-840-850-pros